# blacklist the Judaism and Jewish tags

Tags: feature-request, specific-tag

I request that the [jewish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish) and [judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tags be [blacklisted](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list). This is the Judaism Stack Exchange site: every question on it is "Jewish" in some sense. The tags are thus meaningless.

Comment: [similar](/q/2114/)

Comment: I agree: It would be like having a "computer-programming" tag on Stack Overflow.  There are *some* questions on Mi Yodeya that pertain to non-Jews (e.g., [tag:gentiles] and [tag:noahide-laws]), but even those are “Jewish” in the sense of referencing Jewish literature or gentiles' interactions with the Jewish people.

Comment: As we say in Hebrew, תכל'ס (Tachless).